# How to access apriltag library onto flutter application

Tags: c, flutter, apriltags

I am currently creating an app on Flutter to track Apriltags, I am using the Apriltag library created by the [University of Michigan](https://april.eecs.umich.edu/software/apriltag), and this library is written in C. I need help figuring out the steps on how to be able to get access to this C library.

Comment: Please add a list of the things you've already tried in order to access the library. Code snippets to show your work are helpful too.

Comment: But he's tried nothing, and he's all out of ideas!